# Add additional parameter to JQGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I'm not sure how to best phrase this, especially while trying to research it.  I am trying to add an additional parameter to the search string when my page loads a jqgrid:

http://localhost/jqgrid.cgi?_search=false&nd=1308125954351&rows=25&page=1&sidx=Change&sord=asc

I simply want to append an additional "value=something" to the URL string to use as an argument for my SQL call.  This parameter is not a value contained within the grid, it is merely a value that I wish to use in a WHERE clause from a page that is used to build the grid.

Desired result:

http://localhost/jqgrid.cgi?_search=false&nd=1308125954351&rows=25&page=1&sidx=Change&sord=asc**&value=something**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you use `mtype:"GET"` you can use `postData` to add new parameter:

```
postData: {
    value: "something"
}
```

or even

```
postData: {
    value: function() {
        return $("#anyPageElement").val(); // or other method which read the value
    }
}
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928371/how-to-filter-the-jqgrid-data-not-using-the-built-in-search-filter-box/2928819#2928819) for details.